# Group the properties of an object by types

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing a service using WebAPI and one of client objects needs to be passed to my API with the properties grouped into buckets of individual types.

So my datacontract looks like

```
public class MyObject
{
   public string SourceId { get; set; }
   List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> StringValuedProperties { get; set; }
   List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> IntegerValuedProperties { get; set; }
   List<KeyValuePair<string, DateTime>> DateTimeValuedProperties { get; set; }
}
```

There is a strong reason why I need to group the properties into buckets for specific types and explaining it would take an essay :)

Just wondering if anyone has done this before in a better way or is this the only way?

Comment: You need to give more information why this? Btw, use Tuple in lieu of KeyValuePair in this case.

Comment: Are you asking whether there is a better way than the model you have? Something tells me it will be hard for anyone to make a statement of it being better when the reasons for taking this approach aren't clear.